# Ordering in Priority_Queue

Tags: queue, priority-queue

I am trying to learn how to use priority_queue vs queue. I have this code for a priority_queue that's supposed to get input from users. The input is a chore and the priority number of the chore. They can enter as many as they want and it's supposed to output them in order. My problem is that it's not outputting them in order. I'm not sure if it's in my main or in my overloaded < operator function. Here is my Chore.h code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
//#ifndef CHORE_H;
//#define CHORE_H;

class Chore{
public:
    Chore(){priorityNum=0;choreName="";}
    std::string getName (Chore c1)const{return choreName;}
    int getPriorityNum(Chore c1)const{return priorityNum;}
    bool operator <(const Chore c1)const;
    std::ostream& output(std::ostream& cout,const Chore c)const;
    std::istream& input(std::istream& cin);
private:
    std::string choreName;
    int priorityNum;
};
//#endif
```

Here's my Chore.cc code:

```
#include"Chore.h"
using namespace std;

bool Chore::operator <(const Chore c1)const{
Chore c2;
int c1Num=c1.getPriorityNum(c1);
int c2Num=c2.getPriorityNum(c2);
return c1Num<c2Num;
/*if(c1Num<c2Num)
    return true;

else if(c1Num==c2Num)
    return true;

else
    return false;*/
}

std::ostream& Chore::output(std::ostream& cout,const Chore c)const{
cout<<endl<<"Chore: "<<getName(c)<<endl;
cout<<"chore Priority: "<<getPriorityNum(c); 
}

std::istream& Chore::input(std::istream& cin){
cout<<endl<< "Enter chore name:";
cin >>choreName;
cout<<endl<<"Enter priority number:";
cin >>priorityNum;
}
```

my main is below:

```
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>
#include"Chore.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
std::priority_queue<Chore>myChores;
Chore tmp;
bool enterAnother=true;

//input loop
while(enterAnother){
    char c;//checks if they want to continue
    tmp.input(cin);
    myChores.push(tmp);
    cout<<endl<<"Want to enter another chore?(y for yes, n for no)";
    cin >>c;
    if(c=='y'|| c=='Y')
        enterAnother=true;
    else
        enterAnother=false;
}

//output loop
while(!myChores.empty()){
    tmp = myChores.top();
    myChores.top().output(cout,tmp);
    myChores.pop();
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is in C++. I just realized that i forgot to mention that.

Comment: It looks like the declaration of your `operator <` has errors. That code does not look like it'll compile. Or if it does, won't do what you want. Hard to say what the problem is unless you fix that. Also, please edit your question and indent your code properly. Note that tabs don't work well; use spaces.